# I have installed lampp and in Firefox. No /var/www

Tags: apache2, xampp

I have installed xampp (Ubuntu 16) and `http://localhost` shows everything is working fine. But there is no `/var/www` directory .

Comment: So? Why do you expect a 3rd party app to follow linux's filesystem? See `.xampp/apache/conf/http.conf` on what directory it is using

Comment: Well being new Ubuntu I assumed it was what I read everywhere. I do not know how to see the file you gave? Can you help?

Comment: I would advice to delete it and install our own LAMP with `sudo apt install lamp-server^` -ALL- documentation you will find will be tailored to that version of a webserver setup and will use all the correct directories (like /var/www/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamp , *Apache* use different `DocumentRoot` for its stuffs . You can find *Apache* configuration under `/opt/lamp/httpd` .

Comment: /opt/lampp does not have a httpd but i did find opt/lampp/htdocs which seems to be the locartion of the website. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @farley Great to hear . Your welcome